# Google Cloud Function : Default file storage path

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am having a simple google cloud function, that creates a json file from a json string using the below code.

```
    final_json = "{
    'InclusionFilenames': [
        'Inc_File1.csv',
        'Inc_File2.csv',
        'Inc_File3.csv',
        'Inc_File4.csv'
    ],
    'ExclusionFilenames': [
        'Exc_File1.csv',
        'Exc_File2.csv',
        'Exc_File3.csv',
        'Exc_File4.csv'
    ]
}"
    with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(final_json,outfile)
```

When i trigger the function, the function runs without any error. But i am not able to find the sample.json file anywhere. What is the default storage path for the files created like in above code?

Comment: "But i am not able to find the sample.json file anywhere" - where are you looking? You're creating a file in the container that's running the function... but how are you expecting to find that?

Comment: What's your use case and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @JonSkeet I was looking for the file in my GCS bucket. 
The path is gs://gcf-v2-sources-xxxxxxxx-asia-south1/[my_function_name]/

Comment: @raja_89: Why would you expect a file written to your container to automatically show up in GCS? Cloud Storage is used for the sources, but that doesn't mean it's the file system for the function. If you want to write a file to GCS, you need to do so explicitly. The code-only answer shows an example of this, although I can't vouch for its accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions write to fs under `/tmp`. Did you try that path already?